# SimpleXml can't use values in equations

Tags: php, simplexml

So there's probably something I've missed something or there's a really simple solution.

My code is as follows:

```
$nationname = $_GET["nam"];
$nationxml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.nationstates.net/cgi-bin/api.cgi?nation=" . $nationname);  
$environment = (float) $nationxml-> GOVT -> ENVIRONMENT;
$mod = 4;
```

I get a value from the Xml node ENVIRONMENT. However if I try and use it as follows:

```
$environment = $environment * $mod;
echo($environment);
```

Nothing! The 'manipulation'(or whatever you want to call it) doesn't appear to happen. 
does anybody know a solution?

__

So an XML file could be like this one: https://www.nationstates.net/cgi-bin/api.cgi?nation=southern+ageena, where

```
  <ENVIRONMENT>15.3</ENVIRONMENT>
```

so I would expect $environment * $mod to equal 61.2 and thus echo 61.2, But it doesn't

Comment: what do you get as opposed to what you expect. what is the sample XML ?

Comment: Please look at the updated question, Thanks!

Comment: the same code works for me, it echos 61.2.  What output ARE you getting ?

By chance do you have error logging enabled ? At first i was getting an error like this until i changed to http instead of https

PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;https&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?